# Automator Workflows How

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm trying to follow the instructions here

http://snowleopardtips.net/tips/everything-you-need-to-know-about-screen-captures.html

under "Installing the Folder Action."

First it suggests a folder I don't have

```
~/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions/
```

so I created it. But the rest of the instructions don't work as the Finder wants a scpt. How can I get my

```
Rename Screen Captures.workflow
```

to fire on Desktop folder changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason it doesn't show up in the list is that it was created with an older version of Automator. Double-click it, save it again, done.

[image]

---

Alternatively, just recreate the Folder Action shown in the screenshot directly above the *Installing* section. This will set up the Folder Action for *Desktop*. Saving the Folder Action will store it in the folder you indicate, and make it available as a Folder Action:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks. we should rename superuser on the OSX side to Daniel Beck.